# How to make vector pick 3 possible values depending on last value in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

In **R** I am trying to create a vector of 12 numbers. The first number is 40 from 40 it can either go down by 1 with probability 0.5, stay the same with probability 0.2 or go up by 1 with probability 0.3. The next value depends on the last value. For example, a possible vector could be:

```
           40 39 38 37 37 38 37 36 37 38 39 39
```

I have tried several different methods but I am unable to get any to work. My latest attempt was:

`xx=c()
num <- 60
for (i in 1:12){
  xx[i] <- sample(x=c(num,num+5,num+10),size=1,prob = probs)}`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You said "The next value depends on the last value." In your code above, how are you making sure this is the case?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, that is why I asked the question.
My thought process for my code was it would do it for each i, obviously I was wrong. I am quite novice with coding

Comment: Please elaborate more on the algorithm. What is the end result? For each element of the first vector a new value based on the probabilities you describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your initial value and add the difference based on the probabilities you specified:

```
x <- 40

for (i in 2:12){
    x[i] <- x[i-1]+sample(c(-1, 0, 1), size=1, prob=c(.5, .2, .3))
}

x
[1] 40 41 41 40 41 40 39 39 40 39 38 38
```